# Merge tags: mysql-workbench and mysqlworkbench

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

On Stack Overflow there are separate tags for [mysqlworkbench](/questions/tagged/mysqlworkbench) and [mysql-workbench](/questions/tagged/mysql-workbench).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merged all [mysqlworkbench](/questions/tagged/mysqlworkbench) into [mysql-workbench](/questions/tagged/mysql-workbench).